# Is it possible to change a variable from String to Number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, types

I would like to set a variable that will store the return value of functions. The return value can either be a string, number or boolean but I don't have any guarantee which one of them will be returned.

Is it possible to use the variable to store either a number, string or boolean depending on the type that the functions will return without applying any conversions?

For example, first I declare `var returnValue = 0`. Then a function `functionA`may return the string `'passed'` and I want to store it in `returnValue` by writing `returnValue = functionA()`. Then another function `functionB`may return `10` or `false` and I would like to use `returnValue` by writing `returnValue = functionB()`. Can it be done?

Comment: _Can it be done?_ Answer is __Yes__ as JavaScript is untyped/Weakly typed.

Comment: … Have you tried it?

Comment: This was more of a question for my own interest on javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

In Javascript, a variable can store any type of data as JS is ***untyped*** as referred in the comments in the main question.

```js
function fn(type) {
  if(type == 'string') return 'passed';
  if(type == 'number') return 1;
  if(type == 'boolean') return true;
}

let returnedValue;
returnedValue = fn('string');
console.log(returnedValue, typeof returnedValue);

returnedValue = fn('number');
console.log(returnedValue, typeof returnedValue);

returnedValue = fn('boolean');
console.log(returnedValue, typeof returnedValue);
```